# Вывод даных после арифметики

Tags: c, алгоритм, арифметика

Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе числа ,например 12345, вывод был равен суме 1+2+3+4+5=15 и потом 1+5=6.
Язык Си. Большое спасибо за ответ!
Не могу придумать как сделать это. Тоесть в голове понимаю, но написать в коде не понимаю как.

Мой пример, но наверное он ничего не даст

```
 #include <stdio.h>
        int main(){
            int isicc >= 0;
            printf ("Enter a cislo isic: ");
            scanf ("%d", &isicc);
            if isicc >=0 {
                
        
        
            }
        }
```

Comment: Выложите свои попытки решить задачу, даже если все неудачные!

Comment: Выложенные код я бы не рассматривал как попытку, но по нему я вижу вы новичок, так что единственное что могу вам посоветовать. Начать учить основы языка.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите разложить число на цифры и найти сумму этих цифр? Если да, то подсказки: младшая цифра числа получается так -- `d = num % 10;` Число без младшей цифры --  `num = num / 10;` Все, что вам осталось, это написать цикл в котором вы суммируете цифры.  Очевидно, что цикл должен завершаться, когда число станет равным нулю. / Попробуете сами облечь эти подсказки в код программы?